# Having some confusion with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, strcpy, strchr

I have the following code that I'm trying to decipher from a former colleague:

```
void getIP(int p){
    char tstr[80];
    char *pt;
    strcpy(ipBuf,"NA");
    if(p==-1)return;
    
    strcpy(tstr, panes[p].stream.c_str());
    pt=strchr(tstr,':');
    if(pt){
        *pt='x'; //Blank first one
        pt=strchr(tstr,':');
        if(pt){
            *pt='\0';
            
            strcpy(ipBuf,&tstr[7]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm relatively inexperienced with C++ so was hoping I could get some help with how this code works. Its purpose I think is to take a camera stream address and strip the port number and any extra stuff off to just give an IP address. I cannot understand through how it achieves this other than it seems to use ":" as a delimiter at a couple of stages?

To explain the function a little more, int p is a position on the grid, then it takes the stream address from that grid square and puts it into tstr.

But any explanation beyond that is much appreciated.

Comment: the code is incomplete. `ipBuf`  and `panes` is used without being declared

Comment: It seems to operate on global C strings? What is the purpose of the function?  I'd try to figure that out and rewrite it in C++ style instead

Comment: I believe they are declared elsewhere. But panes is a list of camera streams, and ipbuf I believe is a buffer to store IP addresses and is filled by this function

Comment: *I'm relatively inexperienced with C++* -- The code is practically all `C` and little, if any C++.

Comment: I stand corrected then, I'm inexperienced with C and C++

Comment: `char tstr[80];; strcpy(tstr, panes[p].stream.c_str());` -- This makes no sense to do this if `stream` is a `std::string`.  Why not have `tstr` as a `std::string` also?  Then it's a simple `tstr = panes[p].stream;`.   Looks like your former colleague was a `C` programmer trying their hand at C++, but couldn't let `C` go by the wayside, for whatever reason.

Comment: Let me try to summarize this operation in plain english,

strchr function helps to find the first occurence of location of ':' within the search string. Probably you are interested in the second occurence of ':' in the search string. Hence, you are replacing the first occurrence of : with x and then running a search for : again.

This returned location potentially acts as a marker for fetching the data of interest, in this case, ip address

Comment: This _is_ C++ even if looking a lot like C. It should only be tagged C++, not C. See the respective tag wikis for tag usage guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> I [...] was hoping I could get some help with how this code works.

> ```
>     strcpy(tstr, panes[p].stream.c_str());
> ```

Copy the contents of the `std::string` designated by `panes[p].stream` into array `tstr`, yielding an independent copy as a C string.

> ```
>     pt=strchr(tstr,':');
>     if(pt){
>         *pt='x'; //Blank first one
> ```

Locate the first appearance of a `':'` character in the local copy of the string.  If the character is found, then replace it with an `'x'`.

> ```
>         pt=strchr(tstr,':');
>         if(pt){
>             *pt='\0';
> ```

Locate the (new) first appearance of a `':'` character in the local copy of the string.  If it exists, replace it with a `'\0'`, which will be recognized as a string terminator.  That is, truncate the string at that point.

> ```
>             strcpy(ipBuf,&tstr[7]);
> ```

Copy the contents of the local C string, starting at the eighth character (because arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1), into the space to which `ipBuf` points.  The magic number 7 is suspicious here, but I don't have enough information to be able to determine whether it is erroneous.  My guess would be that the code is assuming that the original first colon will always appear at index 6, with the result that the substring between the (original) first and second colons is copied, but there are cleaner, clearer, more efficient ways to do that.

#### Improved version, with more C++

... and better names, and no unnecessary copying, and explanatory comments:

```
void getIP(int pane_index){
    if (pane_index >= 0) {
        // for clarity and convenience
        std::string &url_string = panes[pane_index].stream;

        // hardcoded per the original code
        const size_t ip_offset = 7;

        // Locate the first colon, if any, after the start of the ip address
        size_t colon_index = url_string.find(':', ip_offset);

        if (colon_index != std::string::npos) {
            // Extract the name / IP address as the substring starting at
            // offset 7 and stopping just before the second colon
            size_t ip_len = colon_index - ip_offset;

            strncpy(ipBuf, url_string.c_str() + ip_offset, ip_len);
            ipBuf[ip_len] = '\0';          
            return;
        } // else there are no colons after the start of the ip address
    } // else an invalid pane index was given

    // no machine name / IP address is available
    strcpy(ipBuf, "NA");
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what it's doing! The stream address is rtsp:// so that makes sense it's 7. The reason why I am debugging this old code is because a new camera is including admin:admin@'address' with admin:admin being a user and password. So that's screwing things up and it's pointing to an IP of admin. Can you suggest a way to remedy this?

Comment: @Cm1602, that would be a completely different question.  We tend to react poorly to "please write code for me" questions, but if you are having trouble implementing what you need then perhaps we can help you figure out why your attempts are not working.  In a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in the previous comment, the function searches for the second occurence of ':' in tstr string and if it is found, replaces it with null character, effectively cutting off any remaining characters from the string. Than the characters in the string from index [7] to the null character (previously ':') are copied to ipBuf. For example, let say url is rtsp://192.168.0.200:551/stream.sdp. Digit 1 in "192" has index [7] in the string. So copying from that position to the second ":" (or null char) would copy "192.168.0.200".